statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot of a MultiIndex DataFrame
I have collected the frequencies in which combinations of certain categorical parameters occur in a DataFrame. Applying a groupby operation produced another DataFrame with a MultiIndex. Now I would like to visualize the frequencies in a mosaic plot. This is what I have tried:
rows=[
    {"Mode":"ID", "SortBy":"Start", "SortDir":"ASC", "count":10},
    {"Mode":"ID", "SortBy":"Start", "SortDir":"DESC", "count":100},
    {"Mode":"FULL", "SortBy":"End", "SortDir":"DESC", "count":1000}
]
df=pd.DataFrame(rows)
hdf=df.groupby(["Mode", "SortBy", "SortDir"]).sum("count")
mosaic(hdf, index=hdf.index)

But it fails with the following error:
KeyError: "None of [MultiIndex([('FULL',   'End', 'DESC'),\n            (  'ID', 'Start',  'ASC'),\n            (  'ID', 'Start', 'DESC')],\n           names=['Mode', 'SortBy', 'SortDir'])] are in the [columns]"

I was able to produce a diagram using
mosaic(hdf, ["count"])

But this is obviously not what I want: it shows three same-sized rectangles labelled 10, 100, 1000, whereas I was expecting the categories Mode, SortBy, SortDir arranged around the axes and the rectangles reflecting the proportions of counts.

After looking at several other examples it dawned on me that the problem are the levels (combinations) that are missing from the multi-index.
When I reindex the hierarchical dataframe on the cartesion product of the categories and then replace the resulting NaNs with a small numerical value (zero wouldn't be accepted either), it works
hdf=df.groupby(["Mode", "SortBy", "SortDir"])["count"].sum()
mosaic(hdf.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(hdf.index.levels)).fillna(0.01))

(note that groupby is used a little differently here to construct hdf compared to my question)

Seems like a bug to me that mosaic cannot handle this internally, but maybe I'm missing an option?

One way of achieving this is
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows = [
    {"Mode": "ID", "SortBy": "Start", "SortDir": "ASC", "count": 10},
    {"Mode": "ID", "SortBy": "Start", "SortDir": "DESC", "count": 100},
    {"Mode": "FULL", "SortBy": "End", "SortDir": "DESC", "count": 1000}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

hdf = df.groupby(["Mode", "SortBy", "SortDir"]).sum("count")
print("\nGrouped DataFrame:")
print(hdf)

data = {(mode, sortby, sortdir): count for (mode, sortby, sortdir), count in hdf['count'].items()}

data = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if value > 0}
print("\nData for mosaic plot:")
print(data)

if not data:
    print("Error: Data dictionary is empty after filtering zero values.")
else:
    def props(key):
        return {'color': 'lightblue'}

    def labelizer(key):
        return '\n'.join(key)

    data_flat = {(str(mode) + '-' + str(sortby) + '-' + str(sortdir)): count for (mode, sortby, sortdir), count in data.items()}

    print("\nFlattened data for mosaic plot:")
    print(data_flat)

    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 40))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
    mosaic(data_flat, title='Mosaic Plot of Mode, SortBy, and SortDir', properties=props, labelizer=labelizer, ax=ax)
    plt.show()

which gives

If you want to add coloring:
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

rows = [
    {"Mode": "ID", "SortBy": "Start", "SortDir": "ASC", "count": 10},
    {"Mode": "ID", "SortBy": "Start", "SortDir": "DESC", "count": 100},
    {"Mode": "FULL", "SortBy": "End", "SortDir": "DESC", "count": 1000}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

hdf = df.groupby(["Mode", "SortBy", "SortDir"]).sum("count")
print("\nGrouped DataFrame:")
print(hdf)

data = {(mode, sortby, sortdir): count for (mode, sortby, sortdir), count in hdf['count'].items()}

data = {key: value for key, value in data.items() if value > 0}
print("\nData for mosaic plot:")
print(data)

if not data:
    print("Error: Data dictionary is empty after filtering zero values.")
else:
    counts = np.array(list(data.values()))
    norm_counts = (counts - counts.min()) / (counts.max() - counts.min())
    colors = cm.viridis(norm_counts)

    flattened_keys = {f"{mode}-{sortby}-{sortdir}": colors[i] for i, (mode, sortby, sortdir) in enumerate(data.keys())}

    def props(key):
        flattened_key = '-'.join(key)
        return {'color': flattened_keys[flattened_key]}

    def labelizer(key):
        return '\n'.join(key)

    data_flat = {'-'.join((mode, sortby, sortdir)): count for (mode, sortby, sortdir), count in data.items()}

    print("\nFlattened data for mosaic plot:")
    print(data_flat)

    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
    mosaic(data_flat, title='Mosaic Plot of Mode, SortBy, and SortDir', properties=props, labelizer=labelizer, ax=ax)
    plt.show()

which gives


Many thanks for working out this solution. I'm not convinced yet though that there isn't a more straightforward solution.
